# Mask some fields when loading hdb in kdb

Tags: database, kdb

If there are two instances: a1 and a2, and both connect to the same hdb. I would like a2 connect to the hdb but add some filter. For example, there is a table called elec.

I would like a2 starts with filtering some of the values. If I write codes and let a2 load it when starting, doesn't that load the information to memory? Is there any way I can load it like normal hdb when starting a2 instance?

Basically, the question is how to mask some fields in one table when loading hdb?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow, can you give a simple reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks terry!  Example: two instances loads the same hdb data. 10 tables in the hdb. both loads from the same directory. If I would like to start a2 instance with loading the hdb but filter the dates for one table and only shows the data before 2017.05.30 only. How can I do that?

Comment: You could look at setting .Q.view in the a2 hdb instance - however this will apply to all tables  http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/dotQ_utilities

q).Q.view 2017.05.30

Comment: Thanks Connor, actually date is just an example. I would like to remove some columns in one table for a2 instance.

Comment: what i think right now is i can delete the table from `. and then in a function load the database and then output the filtered result, but when it didn't work when i delete the table again from `. in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to prevent columns from being returned by select statements be manipulating the table definition in your HDB instance. The below example has a single date paritioned table. We update the definition to a flipped dictionary with only a subset of the columns defined. This however is reversible and will not update the meta of the table in your instance which will still show all columns.

```
q)meta trade
c   | t f a
----| -----
date| d
sym | s   p
size| j
px  | f
side| s

q)flip trade
`sym`size`px`side!`trade


q)`trade set flip `sym`size`px!`trade
q)select from trade where date=2017.05.27
date       sym  size px
------------------------------
2017.05.27 APPl 9968 92.79204
2017.05.27 APPl 9788 94.97189
2017.05.27 APPl 9660 27.62907

q)meta trade
c   | t f a
----| -----
date| d
sym | s   p
size| j
px  | f
side| s
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! this works!!!! By any chance do you know how I can add a filter to the date in the table, so people can only query the data before a certain date?

Comment: Using .Q.view is the easiest way to restrict the available dates but this will apply to all tables in your HDB instance.

Comment: Thanks Gilmer. but there is no way to replace the return value by something else right? ex. in data field, there is "account=1234,cash=3456" i want to make it return cash=3456 only when returning. I know how to do it in a function with query but not sure if I can write something in the q script so when people do normal query the account information can be replaced by blank or something else.

Comment: Because your data is only memory mapped your query will always return the data which is saved on disk. You would need to either pull all your data into memory and update that column, or if this is a permanent data manipulation for all instances use dbmaint.q to amend the data on disk